# Capitalize the first word outputted from MySQL only

Tags: php, mysql, string, capitalize

I am looking to capitalize every letter of the first word that is presented by MySQL and PHP and keep the rest of the words lowercase. How could that be accomplished?

It is stored in the database with only the first letter capitalized, so the real trick is to keep the rest of the words lowercase.

Here is the code pulling the words from the database as of today:

```
<?php

$query0  = "SELECT LCASE(ord) FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$keyword = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];

echo "$keyword, ";

}
?>
```

Comment: If it is stored in the database with the first word capitalized why not just return from the database...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being like this:

```
$query0  = "SELECT LCASE(ord) FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$keywords[] = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];
}
echo ucfirst(implode(', ', $keywords));
echo ".";
?>
```

This presents a line of words that looks like this:

> Deltagende, sosial, pragmatisk, kunnskapsrik, løsningsorientert, samarbeidende, engasjert.

Instead of:

> deltagende, sosial, pragmatisk, kunnskapsrik, løsningsorientert, samarbeidende, engasjert,

This solution was the result of a modification of the solution to a different question regarding how to remove the last comma that I posted here [Remove last comma or prevent it from being printed at all MySQL/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797230/remove-last-comma-or-prevent-it-from-being-printed-at-all-mysql-php)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something...

```
<?
$count = 0;
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    if ($count == 0) {
        $keyword = ucfirst($row0['LCASE(ord)']); // this will capitalize just the first letter
        $keyword = strtoupper($row0['LCASE(ord)']); // this will make the first word in all CAPS (choose which one you want)
    }
    else
        $keyword = strtolower($row0['LCASE(ord)']);

    echo "$keyword, ";
    $count++;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored in the database with the first letter capitalized (how you want it?), why are you intentionally lowercasing it in your query?

If I'm totally confused, the function you want is ucfirst:

```
echo ucfirst($keyword);
```

Edit

```
$index = strpos($word, ' ');
echo ucfirst(substr($word,0,$index)) . substr($word, $index);
```

Comment: The problem is that this will capitalize the first letter of every word, not just the first letter in the first word that is printed. The is only one word for every record in the mysql-table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, use the php method ucfirst($string)

Comment: The problem is that this will capitalize the first letter of every word, not just the first letter in the first word that is printed. The is only one word for every record in the mysql-table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you need this, but it's better accomplished with PHP:

```
$query0  = "SELECT ord FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$keyword = ucfirst(strtolower($row0['ord']));

echo "$keyword, ";

}
```

[**ucfirst:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) upper-case first letter
[**strtolower:**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) lower-case entire string

Comment: The problem is that this will capitalize the first letter of every word, not just the first letter in the first word that is printed. The is only one word for every record in the mysql-table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query0  = "SELECT LCASE(ord) FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

$i=0;
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   if($i == 0){
      $keyword = ucfirst(strtolower($row0['LCASE(ord)']));
      $i++;
   }
   else
      $keyword = strtolower($row0['LCASE(ord)']);

   echo "$keyword, ";

}
```

Comment: The problem is that this will capitalize the first letter of every word, not just the first letter in the first word that is printed. The is only one word for every record in the mysql-table.

Comment: It would be unnecessary to keep incrementing $i. So put it inside the if to make it happen once.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing the LCASE(ord) as follows:

```
<?php

$query0  = "SELECT LCASE(ord) LCaseValue FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $keyword = $row0['LCaseValue'];
    echo "$keyword, ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
ucwords(-yourdata-);
```

this will captialize every word of data .