# Remove last comma or prevent it from being printed at all MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, csv

I am printing a set of words that is placed in a MySQL database and I am retrieving it with PHP. I want to present it as a comma separated list, but I need it not to print or remove the last comma. How could I do this?

I did try to use `rtrim`, but I did not probably do it right.
This is my code as it is today:

```
<?php

$query0  = "SELECT LCASE(ord) FROM `keywords` ORDER BY RAND()";
$result0 = mysql_query($query0);

while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$keyword = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];

echo "$keyword, ";
?>
```

I did try to use `rtrim`, my attempt was something like this (I might be honest enough to say that I am in above my head in this ;) )

```
$keyword = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];
$keywordc = "$keyword, ";
$keyword- = rtrim($keywordc, ', ');
echo "$keyword-, ";
```

As you might imagine, this did not print much (but at least it did not leave me with a blank page...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this by placing the results in an array first

```
$some_array = array();
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   $some_array[] = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];
}
```

then simply:

```
echo "My List: " . implode(', ', $some_array);
// Output looks something like:
My List: ord1, ord2, ord3, ord4
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do:

```
$keywords = array();
while($row0 = mysql_fetch_array($result0, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
   $keywords[] = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];
}

echo implode(',', $keywords);
```

Comment: What do the `$keywords = array();` do? Since, if I remove it it still produces the same result. Although it is a good result.

Comment: That initializes the `$keywords` variable as an array. PHP doesn't require it, but some consider it to be a better coding practice. One error with the above anser is that `$keyword = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];` should be `$keywords[] = $row0['LCASE(ord)'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($string, 0, -1);
```

That removes the last character.

Comment: but how to print it so that it removes the last character from the last word and not the last character from every word?