# How to create comma separated words

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Blog System Where I'm fetching category Name From Database. Here is what I've tried->

```
<li><span>Categories:</span>

<?php
   $a = mysqli_query($connecDB, "SELECT * FROM vector_cat WHERE post_id='$puser'");
   while( $b = mysqli_fetch_array($a) ){
?>
<a href="https://www.twekr.com/free-vectors/<?php echo $b['post_id']; ?>"><?php echo $b['cat_name']; ?></a>, &nbsp;
<?php } ?>

</li>
```

This Results in ->  Fashion, Technology, PHP, Mysql,
The problem I'm Facing is How can i remove the last comma from the result

Comment: Substr($string,0,-1); ?

Comment: Try `rtrim($string, ",")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove last comma or prevent it from being printed at all MySQL/PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797230/remove-last-comma-or-prevent-it-from-being-printed-at-all-mysql-php)

Comment: It's not a possible duplicate, IT IS a duplicate. This must be the simplest question to google. There are probably hundreds of answers on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php).

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the end of str.

```
rtrim($string, ',');
```

Second parameter indicates the character to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you can use `rtrim()` to remove the last comma. Or `substr()` to remove the last few characters.

But to build a comma separated string, I would use `implode()`.

> implode(string $glue, array $pieces)

```
echo implode(',', $yourArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

`rtrim($string, ",")` would remove trailing commas. (For more info read [rtrim on PHP.net](http://php.net/rtrim))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "substr". -1 is for get the last character and 0 for remove the last character

```
$your_text = "Fashion, Technology, PHP, Mysql,";

$last = substr($your_text, 0, -1);
```

hope it help!